# Easymock throws NPE when calling methods on mocked object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, easymock

I'm trying to use this mock in a test class:

```
    @Mock
    private IDPool idPool;

    @Before
    private void before() {
        expect(idPool.getNextFree()).andReturn(TRACK_ID).anyTimes(); //line 63
    }
```

When I run it I get NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.IDPool.getNextFree(IDPool.java:68)
    at com.mycompany.Test.before(Test.java:63)
```

It looks like it tries to run the production code instead of mock? Because the NPE is thrown here in IDPool class:

```
    public final Integer getNextFree() {
        int nextFree;
        synchronized (this.usedIDs) { //line 68
            //...
        }
    }
```

I thought mocks don't use actual implementations? can I mock this object so that it doesn't?

Comment: its because of the final keyword in the method declaration, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I would comment, but I don't have enough reputation.
Your suspicion about EasyMock not being able to mock the final method (or class) is right.
However, you can use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock). I cannot verify it now, but initializing the mock with `PowerMock.createMock(IDPool.class)` should enable final methods mocking.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584789/16137261) and [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-api-easymock/1.7.0/index.html) should help you.